# API call on Wix Live streaming key generation

Tags: automation, live-streaming, velo

I am new to Wix and trying to generate a Live streaming key programmatically. What I want to do is: when one user clicks the "start streaming" button on the WIX website, then generate the live streaming key and send it back via email. Is it possible to generate a key using WIX API calls? Any hints are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be an API for this yet.

Comment: Hi @Sam, thank you for your answer. Then any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Not that I can think of, but I don't know much about the Live Streaming feature in general.